# Displaying content outside the boundaries of a Window

Tags: .net, wpf, window, cliptobounds

So, I am building a part of a UI that is used to display a video stream along with a few other controls beside it.  Without getting into too much detail, the video is a stream from an area scan camera under which is an objective lens and a tissue sample.

The UI provides a "macro" image which represents the tissue sample, and the video is a live feed showing an arbitrary region of the sample at any time.  My idea was to display the video in a tooltip-like area with a stem that maps to the area of the sample that the user is currrently viewing as shown below.  The window can be dragged around, but the stem should stay anchored.  So, I am using a Callout to get that effect.

---

[image: Notice the broken border on the right side. That is where the stem would be.]

---

Notice the broken border on the right side.  That is where the stem would be (Ignore the corners; those areas are transparent but happened to be over a blue background).  However, because this `Callout` is hosted inside of a window, the stem is clipped.  Does anyone know of a way around this, or better yet, a more simple approach?

Clip to bounds is more of a suggestion than a directive (and doesn't work here) and the I do need the window to be draggable.  Any help will be much appreciated as I learn the ins and outs of WPF.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "stem"?  Is that a UI term that I don't know about or something related to your project?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should post a better picture.  The Callout control has an Anchor property use to display a stem like a balloon tooltip has.

Comment: @Jeff M:  There you go, better picture.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement for a Silverlight app I wrote a while back. I included the tail (or stem as you've called it) inside the `Popup` (or separate `Window` as you appear to be using). Thus, there was no chance of it clipping.